How to change Powerbi live dataset source?
I have a fully fledged pbi report with multiple pages and measures.This report is pointing to preprod and I want to change the datasource to prod.(There is no semantic model for prod).
Can I do this with my report unaffected?

Go to Data source settings and choose the data source you wish to modify :

